# Run string as cmd from .NET

Tags: c#, cmd

I want to execute a string in c# as a .cmd. Is this possible without first saving it as a file on disk and then use Process.Start to execute the file? If so, please come with an example of how to do that in C#.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for duplicate. Couldn't find the right search phrase :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe this can be done by simply using `cmd.exe` as your child process, redirecting StandardInput and simply feeding your string into this redirected StandardInput to make cmd.exe interpret it as batch and run it.  The command `echo dir | cmd.exe` works and so I'd expect `Process.Start` to work as well.